Portainer using both '/data' and `/container_data/portainer/data`
If I create a stack and paste a docker-compose.yml in the web editor I can see the docker-compose.yml in /container_data/portainer/data/compose/
If I create a stack using a Git repository to try docker-elk I get this error:
Failed to deploy a stack: Network elk-stack_elk 
Creating Network elk-stack_elk 
Created Container elk-stack-elasticsearch-1 
Creating time="2024-11-25T14:36:25Z" level=warning msg="mount of type `volume` should not define `bind` option" 
Container elk-stack-elasticsearch-1 
Created Container elk-stack-logstash-1 
Creating Container elk-stack-kibana-1 
Creating Container elk-stack-kibana-1 
Created Container elk-stack-logstash-1 
Created Container elk-stack-elasticsearch-1 
Starting Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error mounting "/data/compose/9/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml" to rootfs at "/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml": mount /data/compose/9/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml (via /proc/self/fd/6), flags: 0x5000: not a directory: unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type

and if I go to ssh I can see that on /container_data/portainer/data/compose/ I have 1, 2, 3 and 4, which are docker-compose.yml I started before installing portainer, then I added them to stacks with the same name to fix the this stack was created outside of portainer. control over this stack is limited error, but the elk-stack is nowhere to be seen.
I can see /data/compose/10/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml/ (yes a directory)
Any idea what do I have to do? Mount /data:/data on portainer's docker-compose.yml instead of /container_data/portainer/data:/data?
